# What does norm of a matrix mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was reading the proof of SVD decomposition form here [SVD decomposition proof](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/477577_Chapter_2.pdf). I was able to follow the proof except for one thing, they define norm of a matrix as
$$|A|_2= \text{sup}_{v_1 \in C^n}\;\; |Av_1| >0 , |v|=1$$
They have used it it the proof for showing some entries are $0$ in the decomposed matrix. I looked up wikipedia but am unable to follow, I was able to follow other types of norm defined for matrices though.

Comment: It is not clear to me which page you looked at and which diefinitions you were able to follow if not that one as it appears rather to the top of [Matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) (See the section induced norm also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)

Comment: The norm is the most any vector is "stretched" by the matrix, not taking rotation into account at all. A pure rotation matrix, for instance, has norm $1$, since all vectors are stretched by a factor $1$, including the one that is stretched the most.

Comment: @quid I am referring to the proof in the section "2.0.5  Existence and Uniqueness Theorem"

Comment: Thsi was not what I meant. "I looked up wikipedia but am unable to follow, I was able to follow other types of norm defined for matrices though. " This is unclear to me. Which page did you look at. The one I linked?

Comment: @quid http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm , here I am unable to follow the induced norm which is what they have used in the proof in the link in  my question. Entrywise norm makes sense to me , but I am unable to follow the concept of induced norm.

Comment: Let $B$ be the closed unit ball, and consider all vectors $Ax$, with $x \in B$. Then the induced norm $\|A\|$ is the size (measured by $\|Ax\|$) of the largest vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a *vector* norm $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ one defines the induced matrix norm as the largest value that $|Ax|$ can attain for a vector $x$ of norm $1$.
Equivalenetly, one can define it as the largest value that $|Ax|/|x|$ can attain over all non-zero vectors (this is quite clearly the same).

Intuitively, this makes sense, since it measures by how much the matrix can change the size of a vector. Of course, one still needs to check this actually gives a norm.

This norm then has the nice property that $|Ay| \le ||A|| \  |y|$ for a matrix $A$ and a vector $y$, and also that $||AB|| \le ||A|| \ ||B||$ for two matrices $A,B$.

One can do this definition for any vector norm, there it is done with respect to the $2$-norm.

Another advantage is that  this definition generalizes quite directly to linear operators on Banach spaces.

Comment: thanks now the proof makes sense to me.